# how to display grouped items in django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a django template below:

```
{% regroup budget.productitem_set.all by group_id as grouped_product_list %}
{% for entry in grouped_product_list %}
    {% for item in entry.list %}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.group_id }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

What ends up happening:

```
ID         QUANTITY     GROUP_ID
test123      23            1
test123      24            1
```

What output I would like

```
ID         QUANTITY     GROUP_ID
test123      23            1
             24
```

Answer (score 0):

Your also Looping description and group_Id as well using the count item

Try

```
 {% regroup budget.productitem_set.all by group_id as grouped_product_list %}
{% for entry in grouped_product_list %}
    
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>{{ entry.description }}</td>
             {% for item in entry.list %}
            <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
             {% endfor %}
            <td>{{ entry.group_id }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   
{% endfor %}
```